# How to integrate a variable in src path for an image?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I try to integrate a name from json in a path to an image

I already used this and don't really help because the program "can't resolve" the path:

```js
     "./photos/${{row.name}}.jpg"

     "./photos/${row.name}.jpg"

     "./photos/"+{row.name}+".jpg"

    var x = {row.name}
    "./photos/${x}.jpg"

    {items.map(row =>(
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <Link to="/doctor">
                                                <img
                                                    src={require("./photos/${{row.name}}.jpg")}

                                                    className="d-inline-block align-top"
                                                    alt={""}
                                                />{row.name}
                                            </Link>
                                            </td>
```

I expect `./photos/nameFromJson.jpg` but it can't be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use variables inside a string, the best way to do that is using `template literals`.

The `template literals` should look like this:

```js
`string ${expression} string`
```

So, the code snippet that you provided, should look like this:

```js
{items.map(row => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Link to="/doctor">
        <img
          src={require(`./photos/${row.name}.jpg`)}
          className="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt=""
        />
        <span>{row.name}</span>
      </Link>
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

If your image names are correct, and everything is inside the `photos` then it should work like a charm. Basically you have made a few syntax mistake.